# Replace every NA in a specific column with a value sample from the last 10 non-NA obs

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to circumvent a `for/loop` to replace every (missing value) `NA` in a specific column of a `data.table` in `R` with a value sampled from the last `10` `non-NA` observations earlier in that column?
I am trying to do this without needing a `for loop`.

Follow--up

You are correct (Akrun) but since this is a one time thing, I can do those manually.. Here is an example

```
Date    Temp
1/26/2013   41
1/27/2013   40
1/28/2013   48
1/29/2013   25
1/30/2013   21
1/31/2013   28
1/1/2013    38
1/2/2013    36
1/3/2013    31
1/4/2013    32
1/5/2013    39
1/6/2013    38
1/7/2013    40
1/8/2013    NA
1/9/2013    NA
1/10/2013   NA
1/11/2013   NA
1/12/2013   NA
1/13/2013   31
1/14/2013   30
1/15/2013   31
1/16/2013   38
1/17/2013   45
1/18/2013   46
1/19/2013   51
1/20/2013   47
```

I would like to replace the `NA` values by sampling from the previous history of temps.. I ended up writing a for loop that worked fine.. but searching for more computationally efficient code
Below is my function

```
i<-c()
a.obs<-c()
x<-c()
Fun_missingtemp <- function(x){
   for(i in 1:length(x$Tavg)){
     while (is.na(x$Tavg[i])){
     a.obs<-x$Tavg[(i-11):i-1]
     x[i, Tavg:=sample(a.obs, 1, replace=TRUE)]
     }  
   }
 x
}
```

Comment: Please provide a small example dataset and expected result

Comment: Your description is also not very specific.  Suppose the missing value is at the 1st row, how do you want to replace?  The last 10 non-NA observations may not be met if the missing value occurs in the first 10 elements.

Comment: A non-data.table solution fast option using `vapply` would be `indx <- which(is.na(df1$Val)); df1$Val[indx] <- vapply(indx, function(i) {x <- tail(na.omit(df1$Val[1:i]),10); if(length(x)>0) sample(x,1) else NA}, 0)` where `Val` is the `Specific Column`

Comment: You are correct (Akrun) but since this is a one time thing, I can do those manually.. Here is an example

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like your betters :)

Comment: Posted the comments as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution would be

```
indx <- which(is.na(df1$Val))
df1$Val[indx] <- vapply(indx, function(i) {
           x <- tail(na.omit(df1$Val[1:i]),10)
           if(length(x)>0) sample(x,1) else NA}, 0)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(95)
df1 <- data.frame(Col=LETTERS[1:20],Val=sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, 
      replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```